# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int32'

Tags: swift4

I'm trying to set a variable time delay for a timer in Swift4, but when I put in the variable I get the error:

```
Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int32'
```

I used the code:

```
let when = (DispatchTime.now() + (5 * x))
```

The Variable "x" is an Int32

Please help if you know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let x: Int32 = 2
let when = (DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds + (5 * UInt64(x)))
```

The problem is that you can not sum different types. And DispatchTime is represented using 64 bits (unsigned) so you can cast it using `UInt64(x)`.

To get the `UInt64` from DispatchTime you can use `uptimeNanoseconds` or `rawValue`

Answer (score 59):

```
var dispatchAfter = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(1)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + dispatchAfter, execute: {
    // Do your thing
})
```